# UITableView Header Snaps to the Top of the Screen on Certain iPhones

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Sometimes (but not all the time!) on iPhones (and iPhone simulators) I notice my UITableView header has this 'snapping' behavior that, when I try to drag down from the top of the screen it snaps back up instead of fluidly moving back up like a tableView normally behaves.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of this bug, what causes it, or how I can fix it? I feel like it might have something to do with UITableViewHeader but I'm not sure.

Unfortunately, I cannot share the code, but I don't believe it is something in the code. I manually commented on almost every line of the code and the problem persists!

[image]

Comment: Hi Alex, can you please share a GIF showing the issue? Is it something like this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCRlT_hqz4Y ?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I can make a gif since the screen has all sorts of company logos on it. It's similar to that but basically if I drag down like in that video, it drags up part way, stops, then snaps up the rest of the way.

Comment: Sure, I understand. The guy who posted this video had also posted this one - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LyKxWwu5M0 which is the issue fixed. You may be able to find something useful in the video's description. I would also suggest putting a link to this video in the post so developers can better understand what is the issue.

Comment: Added a to show the problem.

Comment: @AlexKornhauser can you make a minimal reproducible example project and share Github link?

Comment: are you able to share any code related to this ?

Comment: @AlexKornhausercould you please add the view hierarchy to the question?

Comment: The problem is that this is proprietary code. How can I add a view hierarchy?

Comment: Do you have any `refreshControl` in your `tableView` @AlexKornhauser?

Comment: @AlexKornhauser hard to give solid answer with little information to go on. Please provide either a minimal code repo or snippets, also please share view heirarchy and or storyboard if possible

Comment: Do you have header view on TableView?

Comment: Instead of making conversation long , can you please share your controller code ?

Comment: No refresh control. Unfortunately I cannot share the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here was the problem for me and I'm pretty sure its a bug in XCode/Swift.

At first my navigation controller in the storyboard has this setting: 
[image]

In my code I have the following method declared:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    let hideBar = (viewController == self)
    navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(hideBar, animated: animated)
}
```

Used to disable the navigation bar on the home screen. The combination of these two (if the method is declared on the home screen) causes a bug as shown above. I am able to repeat this bug in a new project.

**The solution to this bug is to check the Show Navigation Bar box on the Navigation Controller**

Answer (score 1):

Since code is not provided for this question, I am answering based on my assumption.

Assumption 1 - Using manual layout.

- If you have code in `layoutSubviews()`. Then you might want to check your calculation again. Make sure view frames are calculated one time in `layoutSubview()` method.

Assumption 2 - View animation is blocked/delayed by some other tasks on main thread.

- Make sure to run no-UI/API code in background thread.

Reuse cell instances: for specific type of cell you should have only one instance, no more.

Don’t bind data at `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method ‘cause at this time cell is not displayed yet. Instead use `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method in the delegate of `UITableView`.

Hey, can you move your header view content in first cell of first section, so that you can avoid header view problem. Then check if snappy problem is occurring.

Comment: Problem persists if I remove the header

Comment: Ok. I think you shoud create dummy app/behaviour similar to main app. If problem not exists in dummy app then compare implementation side by side where you are going wrong in main app.  If you can't find resolution to it, then share code of dummy app/behaviour as it is not proprietary code.